# Avoid run functions from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have somthing like that :

```
$(function(){
    init = {
        actions :{
            settings    : [settings_title(), settings_time(), settings_category(), settings_design(), settings_registration()],         
            timer       : [timer()]             
        }
    };
```

but i don't want that all these functions run immediately when page loads, just when when click :

```
$('.save').click(function(){
    init.actions.settings[1];
});
```

or i something missed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be looking for this:

```
$(function(){
    init = {
        actions :{
            settings    : [settings_title, settings_time, settings_category, settings_design, settings_registration],         
            timer       : [timer]             
        }
    };
// ...
```

No `()` after the function names, so we're just referring to the function object (putting a reference to it in the array), not *calling* it and putting its return value in the array.

And then:

```
$('.save').click(function(){
    init.actions.settings[1]();
    // Note ----------------^^
});
```

...which calls the function we stored in the array at index 1.

---

Side note: Unless you have a declaration for `init` somewhere that you haven't shown, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).